# QAbstractNativeEventFilter not receive XCB_KEY_PRESS

Tags: c++, qt, xcb

I'm building a Qt application that process native xcb events. But cannot receive key press event or mouse events.
Below are my codes.

```cpp
// myfilter.h
class MyFilter : public QObject, public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyFilter(xcb_connection_t *conn, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyFilter();

    virtual bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message,
            long *result) override;

signals:

private:
    xcb_connection_t *_conn;
    xcb_window_t _rootWindow;
};
```

```cpp
// myfilter.cpp
MyFilter::MyFilter(xcb_connection_t *conn, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    this->_conn = conn;

    xcb_screen_t *screen;
    screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(this->_conn)).data;
    this->_rootWindow = screen->root;
    qDebug() << "Root window: " << this->_rootWindow;

//    xcb_grab_key(this->_conn, 1, screen->root, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY, XCB_GRAB_ANY,
//        XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC);
    QCoreApplication::instance()->installNativeEventFilter(this);
}

MyFilter::~MyFilter()
{
    xcb_disconnect(this->_conn);
}

bool MyFilter::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType,
        void *message, long *result)
{
    if (eventType == "xcb_generic_event_t") {
        xcb_generic_event_t *ev = static_cast<xcb_generic_event_t*>(message);
        auto responseType = ev->response_type & ~0x80;
        switch (responseType) {
        case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
            qDebug() << "XCB_KEY_PRESS";
            break;
        case XCB_EXPOSE:
            qDebug() << "XCB_EXPOSE";
            break;
        case XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY:
        {
            xcb_property_notify_event_t *property_notify = (xcb_property_notify_event_t*)ev;
            qDebug() << "XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY" << property_notify->atom << property_notify->window;
            break;
        }
        case XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE:
        {
            xcb_client_message_event_t *client_message = (xcb_client_message_event_t*)ev;
            qDebug() << "XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE" << client_message->window;
            break;
        }
        default:
            qDebug() << responseType;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Not a xcb_generic_event_t";
    }

    return false;
}
```

and

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QX11Info>

#include <xcb/xcb.h>

#include "myfilter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    xcb_connection_t *conn = QX11Info::connection();

    MyFilter myFilter(conn);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to receive `XCB_KEY_PRESS` but when I run this application and press any key, it always prints 85 which is defined as `XCB_ALLOC_NAMED_COLOR`.
What is this event and why response_type reports this rather than `XCB_KEY_PRESS`?

Comment: Could you run your program (and check that the event still has number 85) and then afterwards run `xdpyinfo -queryExtensions | grep '(opcode'`? We are looking for the largest base event that is `<= 85`. That will tell us which X11 extension the event is from.

Comment: If I were to guess: Qt uses the X Keyboard extension and thus does not get "normal" KeyPress events, but events from this extension. In this case, the command above would find `XKEYBOARD`. In fact, in my X11 server, `XKEYBOARD` has `base event: 85`, but that does not mean that your X11 server will do the same.

Comment: I tried `xcb_grab_keyboard` and now the keyboard events are receiving. But this function eats all keyboard inputs so entire keys not working. I'm finding other solution.